# Issue with keeping a div class floating down with the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying a few things but cannot get it to work. I have a div in the right column and I want it to float down to a certain point with the page while scrolling.

```
<div class="stickyDiv">
 <div class="section mod-sticky" style="position: fixed; top: 70px;">
 <p>Always float with page</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Is there any easy way to do this with jQuery? Or just css?

made a quick jsfiddle what I want is that as soon as it reaches class contentb it will scroll with the page

https://jsfiddle.net/agwrbjh8/1/

thanks

Comment: Can you share a live `jsfiddle` demo?

Comment: You need to add an `$(window).on("scroll")` function and in that you need to check `$(document).scrollTop()` for whatever the value you want that _certain point_ you mentioned to be.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/agwrbjh8/1/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood you.  Do you mean something like this:

```css
.mod-sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="stickyDiv">
  <div class="section mod-sticky">
    <p>floater</p>
  </div>
  dasf asd asdf asdf
  <p style="height:800px">Lorem... long text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `float` does not apply to `fixed` elements. So I've removed it. Also those 200 `<br>` were killing my morning coffee...

Comment: ha! thank you... the `br`s were just for the scrolling visual

Comment: so is the `<p style="height:800px">` ;=)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [sticky-kit jQuery plugin](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/).

And you would use it as so:

```
$('.stickyDiv').stick_in_parent({
    parent: $('.content'),
    offset_top: 70
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/v2fuqb6n/2/)**

Had to restructure your HTML so that `.stickyDiv` is a child of the content div you intend to stick within, and then also added a `margin-left` to get it to the right of the content area. Might not work for your situation but I don't see how you can get it to stick how you want with your original markup.